# Objective C runtime - Associatet Objects problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I was wondered , I trying to access an object  with

```
id objc_getAssociatedObject(id object, void *key)
```

but it is not working when method is being called from

```
-(void)encodeWithCoderOv:(NSCoder *)aCoder
```

It's return null .

Please help !!!
here is code.

```
+ (void)load { 
    MethodSwizzle(self, @selector(encodeWithCoder:),@selector(encodeWithCoderOv:)); 
    MethodSwizzle(self, @selector(initWithCoder:),  @selector(initWithCoderOv:)); 
}


// this method will return associated Object when its being called from anywhere,but will
// return null when its being called from  encodeWithCoder.

- (id)getObject {
    return [self associatedObject];
}


- (id)associatedObject {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&ObjectKey)retain];
}

- (void)setAssociatedObject:(UIImage*)newObject {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self,&ObjectKey,newObject,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

 -(void)encodeWithCoderOv:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:[self associatedObject] forKey:@"someKey"]; 
    NSLog(@"object in encoder %@",[self associatedObject]); //  object is null
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Not working *how*? It crashes? It's `nil`? It turns the screen blue? Be specific please.

Comment: when I trying to call objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&ObjectKey) It returns null

Comment: only if it's called from encodeWithCoder

Answer (score 0):

Pass ObjectKey, not &ObjectKey.

Comment: Depends how ObjectKey is defined. If it's a `void` pointer, that's right. If it's a `char` or some other type (as in Apple's example code) then you have to pass by address.

Comment: Yeah, we need to see more code -- what is ObjectKey? Is it a static, global, or instance variable? Array or scalar? Also, make sure that "self" has exactly the same pointer value in setAssociatedObject and encodeWithCoder using NSLog(@"%p", self).